# JNI binaries not included in JAR

Tags: java, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm building javacv(http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) by myself. The problem is that the resulting jar file does not includes libjni*.so files.
The official release of javacv has three jar:
javacv.jar
javacpp.jar
javacv-linux-x86.jar (this is where the libjni*.so is located)

I use ant to build the project, and it produces javacv.jar and javacpp.jar, the javacv-linux-x86.rar however, is missing.
When I look at 'build/classes/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/linux-x86', the libjni*.so are there.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Just calling `ant` or maybe `ant jar` should build everything... Still having problems?